# Any way to consolidate index entries on successive pages in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Suppose I use the "mark all" option to make an index entry for every occurrence of some word. And suppose that this word turns up on a number of successive pages, like 10, 11, 12, 13, and 14. Is thee any way to tell Word to combine those entries into a range, i.e. "10-14" in this example? Word is smart enough to consolidate multiple entries on the same page, so it doesn't say 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13. Any way to consolidate ranges?

Yes, I know I can use the "mark range" function, but that requires me to figure out the ranges manually.

Comment: Yiu mean to say that u need all marked index entries in ONE page which are spread around page 10 to 14?

Comment: Frankly, unless the occurrences of the indexed term are part of some larger, continuous section that discusses that term, such that you'd use "mark range" for it, it would be bad indexing practice to combine the page numbers like that – which is probably why Word doesn't do it by default. If the occurrences of the term on pages 10, 11, 12, 13, and 14 are isolated references (and don't represent some larger, continuous discussion of that term), the page references should remain separate. Take a look at any large scholarly work that has an index, and you should see these principles followed.

Comment: @cnread I can certainly see this would not always be right, which is why I thought it should be an option. Sure, you could have 4 references on 4 successive pages that have nothing to do with each other. What I'm seeing in my case, though, is that when there are multiple references on successive pages, in most cases it's because they're in a longer section talking about that thing, and so the word I indexed on keeps coming up over and over in a short range.

Comment: What I find that I'm having to do is look at the generated index, find cases with successive page numbers, then look back to those pages, create a bookmark, create an index on the range, and then delete all the individual index entries within the range one by one. I can't just not index on the word because there are many other references outside these longer sections. So it's a bunch of manual effort.